# Trouble installing on real watchOs device from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

I've been having a lot of trouble installing on a real watchOS device from xcode. It gets stuck on with the tasks you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

I was experiencing these issues a while ago on a final version xcode and couldn't find a solution, repairing with phone didn't help and also it takes a very long time to repair. In the recent month I've been using xcode beta where I could run on my watch without any issues at all. Today I upgraded to xcode 15 and removed the beta version and now I'm having this issue again. I tried removing ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport but it didn't help either.

Update:
I got it installing again by restarting my watch and waiting for like an hour on xcode saying "reconnecting to device" or something like that. But it's again much slower and painful to debug as I remember it used to do. Something is wrong, it was much easier when I was running Beta. I tried switching xcode version to Beta but there is the same problem. Maybe it's having Beta software that eliminates the problem.